# when pushing multiple files into array as base64 it gives DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a vue.js application and i'm adding multiple file uploader with slide option. I'm using below method

```
<input
    id="file-upload"
    ref="file"
    class="custom-file-input"
    multiple
    name="document_file"
    type="file"
    @change="setFile($event)"                            
/>
<label class="custom-file-label selected overflow-hide">{{ $t('Browse') }}</label>
```

```
data() {
        return {
            imageUrls: [],
            img_id: 0,
            currentIndex: 0
        }
    },
```

```
setFile(e) {
    let self = this;
    let reader = new FileReader();

    if(e.target.files.length > 0){
         for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
              alert();
              reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[i]);
              reader.onload = function () {
              self.imageUrls.push(
              {
                id: self.img_id,
                file: reader.result
              });
              self.img_id++;
             }
            }
      console.log('imageUrls: ', self.imageUrls);

    }
   },
```

with the alert object(all the selected files) are being pushed to array. but when i comment the alert it's giving below error

```
DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
```

what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `let reader = new FileReader();`  inside the loop solve the problem

```
setFile(e) {

            let self = this;
            for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[i]);
                reader.onload = function () {
                    self.imageUrls.push({
                        id: self.img_id,    
                        file: reader.result,
                    });
                    self.img_id++;
                };

            }
            console.log(self.imageUrls);

        },
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **FileReader()** object for each files. try this

```
<input
    id="file-upload"
    ref="file"
    class="custom-file-input"
    multiple
    name="document_file"
    type="file"
    @change="setFile"                            
/>
<label class="custom-file-label selected overflow-hide">{{ $t('Browse') }}</label>


data() {
        return {
            images: [],
            imageUrls: [],
            img_id: 0,
            currentIndex: 0
        }
},

setFile(e) {
    let self = this;
    var selectedFiles = e.target.files;

    //let reader = new FileReader();

    for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
        console.log(selectedFiles[i]);
        this.images.push(selectedFiles[i]);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
          //this.$refs.image[i].src = reader.result;
        // console.log(reader.result);

         self.imageUrls.push(
          {
            id: self.img_id,
            file: reader.result
          });
         self.img_id++;

          //console.log(this.$refs.image[i].src);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(this.images[i]);
      }
      console.log('imageUrls: ', self.imageUrls);


    
   },
```

Comment: i found an issue, using 2 for loops cause to append all already exsisting files again. first time working fine. guess first time add 2 files and again browse and add 2 files, it adds 6 files to images array . i'll post the answer below.